# Is it possible to factory reset without losing my google play movies?

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset

I have a few movies downloaded from the google play movies app, and I don't want to re-download all of them. My wi-fi is slow. It would take DAYS to re-download.

Answer (score 0):

If you reset you phone, you lose all google data unless you had a back and restore activated. However if you had offline videos from google play movies then you won't lose this videos since they are saved to your google account and not directly to your device...